# Callback function overloading with generic types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible, in TypeScript, to declare a generic callback type that accepts a variable number of generic type arguments (the number of generic args can be fixed)?

For example:

```js
export interface CustomFn {
  <T1>(value1: T1):  boolean
  <T1,T2>(value1: T1, value2: T2): boolean
  <T1,T2,T3>(value1: T1, value2: T2, value3: T3): boolean
}
```

So that I can do things like:

```js
const t: CustomFn = (a: string) => false
const t2: CustomFn = (a: number, b: string) => false
const t3: CustomFn = (a: boolean, b: string, c: number) => false
```

The above is almost what I want, except it doesn't quite work.

The first line works.

The second and third line complains with a compiler error:

```bash
Type '(a: number, b: string) => any' is not assignable to type 'CustomFn'
```

What is the correct way to declare a callback type that accepts variable generic args (the number of args can be fixed)?

### More Context

This is part of a broader solution. Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```js
export interface ValidationRule {
    name: string
    validator: CustomFn
}
const validationRules: CustomFn[] = [
   {
      name: 'required',
      validator: (s: string) => {
          return s != null
      }
   },
   {
      name: 'greaterThan',
      validator: (value: number, max: number) => {
          return value > max
      }
   }
]
```

### Potential Solution

Maintainability is important. I would be ok if the types had to be unioned like this:

```js
export declare type GenericPredicate = 
    CustomFn<T1> |
    CustomFn<T1,T2> |
    CustomFn<T1,T2,T3> 


export interface ValidationRule {
    name: string
    validator: GenericPredicate
}
const validationRules: CustomFn[] = [
   {
      name: 'required',
      validator: (s: string) => {
          return s != null
      }
   },
   {
      name: 'greaterThan',
      validator: (value: number, max: number) => {
          return value > max
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: `(…args: unknown[]) => unknown` is pretty generic

Comment: um, without losing type safety :)

Comment: Are you down with specifying args' and return types explicitly?

Comment: No, Ideally, I would like it to work like the example above. The reason is to let the complier infer the types based on the assignment. I'm hoping it's possible and there's just something wrong with how i'm declaring the types.

Comment: Could you add more concrete use case? How do you indent to actually use this type? I don't think it's possible (or useful) the way you describe it in the question.

Comment: My confusion is that if you want the variables `t`, `t1`, `t2` to have proper types, you just omit type assertion (the `: CustomFn` part), and there you go. That's true for every possible type.

Comment: This is part of a broader solution, which I haven't included the context. For example, I have generic interface that has as a property, `CustomFn`, and there are varying implementations. Removing `CustomFn` doesn't help because then it wouldn't be part of the interface.

Comment: I think you're not really looking for a better `CustomFn` type but a mechanism to verify that some value is assignable to `CustomFn` without widening it to that type. Hence [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) would be of more use.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wva1rm) for how that might look with your example code. If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining. (Please mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified.)

Comment: @jcalz, the `export type CustomFn = (...args: any[]) => boolean;` the first line is exactly what I was looking for. I've modified your example a little bit (see embedded in question above). I couldn't embed the playground link here - it was too long. If you wanted to post an answer, I'll mark as correct.

Comment: That type doesn't behave how you want as-is, assuming you care about type safety; see [this link](https://tsplay.dev/WyljKm).  (You can use https://tsplay.dev to shorten links.)  Does my original suggestion with `satisfies` work for you?  (Again, @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: I'm doing something similar here in add operation[Here](https://github.com/PhilippDehler/ts-template)

Comment: @jcalz, I do, yes, `satisfies` works for me!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; hopefully today but maybe tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were just looking for a *type*, it would probably be:

```
type CustomFn = (...args: any[]) => boolean;
```

or maybe the safer

```
type CustomFn = (...args: never[]) => boolean;
```

which will accept any function that returns a `boolean` value.

---

But there's a catch: if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable as this type, the compiler will unfortunately forget anything more specific than that the function returns a `boolean`.  Specific information about the number and types of parameters will be lost.

The version with `any[]` will let you call the function with the right parameters:

```
type CustomFn = (...args: any[]) => boolean;
const f: CustomFn = (s: string) => s.toUpperCase() === s.toLowerCase();
f("okay");
```

But it will *also* let you call the function with the *wrong* parameters:

```
try {
    f(123); // wait, no compiler error? 
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e) // RUNTIME ERROR  s.toUppercase is not a function
}
```

On the other hand, the version with `never[]` is so safe that it doesn't even let you call the function with the right parameters:

```
type CustomFn = (...args: never[]) => boolean;
const f: CustomFn = (s: string) => s.toUpperCase() === s.toLowerCase();
f("okay"); // error, this is not allowed!
```

The problem here isn't so much the `CustomFn` *type*, it's with the *values* of that type.

---

My suggestion here would be to replace type annotations with [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  If you write `const vbl: Type = value` then `vbl` will usually only know about `Type` and not a possibly narrower `typeof value`.  On the other hand, if you write `const vbl = value satisfies Type`, then the compiler will make sure that `value` *satisfies* `Type` without widening it.  And `vbl`'s type with be `typeof value`, which might be more specific than `Type`.

For the above example code that becomes:

```
const f = (
    (s: string) => s.toUpperCase() === s.toLowerCase()
) satisfies CustomFn; // okay

f("okay"); // okay
f(123); // compiler error
```

See how `f` is verified as satisfying `CustomFn` but the compiler remembers that it is of type `(s: string) => boolean` so it will allow you to call `f("okay")` and complain about `f(123)`.

---

For your example code, we can do something similar:

```
interface ValidationRule {
    name: string
    validator: CustomFn
}
const validationRules = [
    {
        name: 'required',
        validator: (s?: string) => {
            return s != null
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'greaterThan',
        validator: (value: number, max: number) => {
            return value > max
        }
    },
    // uncomment the following line to see mistake
    // { name: 'mistake', validator: (a: string, b: number) => "oopsie" }
] as const satisfies readonly ValidationRule[];
```

Here we use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to keep track of the exact [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name` properties of the array elements.  And instead of widening `validationRules` to `ValidationRule[]` which would forget everything more specific about it, we just use `satisfies` to make sure it *would* work.

If you made a mistake with `validationRules`, you'd get an error on `satisfies`:

```
const badValidationRules = [
    {
        name: 'required',
        validator: (s?: string) => {
            return s != null
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'greaterThan',
        validator: (value: number, max: number) => {
            return value > max
        }
    },
    { name: 'mistake', validator: (a: string, b: number) => "oopsie" }
] as const satisfies readonly ValidationRule[]; // error!
// ----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ name: "mistake"; validator: (a: string, b: number) => string; }'
// is not assignable to type 'ValidationRule'. 
// string is not assignable to boolean
```

---

And since `validationRules` has not been widened, the compiler can type check more accurately:

```
const someRule = validationRules[Math.floor(Math.random() * validationRules.length)];
/* const someRule: {
    readonly name: "required";
    readonly validator: (s?: string) => boolean;
} | {
    readonly name: "greaterThan";
    readonly validator: (value: number, max: number) => boolean;
} */

if (someRule.name === "greaterThan") {
    someRule.validator(1, 2); // okay
}
```

The compiler knows that `someRule` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where the `name` property can be used to determine the type of `validator`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBYBPJBvAUE-SALujMgMICuUhA9mAGLBIC8SAFAHRcgBOA5lABcSEBgDaAXQCULAHxIARjRoAbCKIDceAvBrBqSAGbDK1OoxbshSajwCWwPjObyoHWgFUYpHmRBQINmdmVjdaABkaAHcIX39AqS0CIzYAIhoAaxB0VMTtfEIeTFxk5MM2AEYAJgBmRKQAegakKJA7QgAaJGAaJF0wGDs1HiRYnhoeAH4kfKQAXz6QQngAC3YIGRLS-F19VQgOFRo+Ng3G5oAlDwA5ABUASQBZAFEkZ4uLgHkLpEBeDcBSnZs7hoXh88HiSDsUG6NEIIiMFGA8EIdj0szmOAxOGIpCQploDCYrE43H41mAEAAbrFJM55Ep9pocLsDMY8VQCRZidZbA4nHIgZ5vLE-AEgiwQoKaJEYnExXlyuksjl6k1RjxxjwuoQVlDIdCenCQCojjEACYAQhwzL0Bj4ljYszYPMKfLpUtBIvi4pCoWBMq98pwMigSyhhjs0HZZkJWhOSuyuQ05yQmWy2KK2FmJ2qdWTav6g2G6s1mMWyzWp02fVt+0Oxyr82tOAchFihgQyAAasa7Gaw3oLhQ1FnkqBIMJeY5ZpTe-3aDwTBzzMBMTb9HDZyo+wPgEO1NDWGJZlttuOIMIAOQ8CAARwodhvZsvHVmyS3O4Xwmdk0nrsc7qntsBA3oQFA8Ew0IWqwwDDiob4EBiyRzK+yRAWO4AXkgl58DeSyxLcKyiC+CH4B+84TN+W4UFhsFgAosRdGAIAAB7CHRDE8IBpGlKB4FMNRyDyMxLE8UhiGoQQaqIv0kDAHCOrIIYqimnySDbhSRC9AEyBgFChAgBkECzGqWDdJhV56dQhkQC+SDkUslHsCAf72I4XQKOxFD0bE7rpDQMBQJGqRNhIIjQiycKhiiUARlGeFmnoKiYD227zqie7DhAkhaNakWKCAZqpZ+GX7lGR4njx55Xje96PhAz6SdsDlflYv42P+-IuKOwHJHxEE2Eg0HdHBYnok1PVnhZ2G4eobY8IRxETe+c6OYu7CCV5PlakgIlbZx3G9X1EBgQNglIMJrFjchE1mdV2FWQZRl2S1TlsC5HVuXwHn7b5Ar+YFwWheFNYbjYYaxZG0IJUlKWrSig5ZTlKZjBMVpqgAtFj2M47jGPyAAfkTxMk6TZMkzgaq3CQyCXnd02pI9NmpMmr3re9rl8j9I3be6U58MmcyXpTzR6oa4VBXwoAKCOtBEDT2HFeliNqJeHAzGq-P6jCRpQJL0uy70DJqKIeW2lFdAQGVlgtaVWVQGIjxLCsHCGEcExsE7OocDwoiJWA4oAFT2fDdsHocECODqUgSFoDTB-lUCW2VwhATDwDJeZE5IKktUPk+LOzOnmds9+UDtfz7rG+owBaAsAA+k1IMXmD3aks34QtRHAIXx2FbDIdpWtVHGjRv07XtPMHQK1dMgsgcNC2hhWMnWUcOeEqsO3eHzYtPebLMSeQGVHBs5UXRVKqzRpuga44EAA)